# JS: Calculate midpoints of lines recursively

Tags: javascript, coordinates, draw

I'm writing a simple drawing application in JS that works with coordinates. I need to find the midpoint of two points recursively in order to draw a line(The midpoint between point A and B, and then the two midpoints between the three resulting points, and so on). See [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSz5r.gif) for a clearer example.

This is a grid/coordinate based drawing app, so simply drawing a line is not possible. It is necessary to get all the coordinates between the points.

I have a function that finds midpoints

```
function findMidpoint(p1,p2){
    return Math.floor((p1+p2)/2);
}
```

And a function that draws the point (I'm also storing the previous points as prevX and prevY

```
setPoint(X,Y);
```

So what I'm doing to draw the midpoints is the following:

```
setPoint(findMidpoint(X,prevX),findMidpoint(Y,prevY));
```

The next set of midpoints:

```
setPoint(findMidpoint(findMidpoint(X,prevX),prevX),findMidpoint(findMidpoint(Y,prevY),prevY));
setPoint(findMidpoint(X,findMidpoint(X,prevX)),findMidpoint(Y,findMidpoint(Y,prevY));
```

As you can see this gets messy very very quickly. I guess there's a recursive way to do this, or some sort of way of looping it a given amount of times, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you get is a line. why do you need the points? you need to specify an end condition where the midpoints action should stop.

Comment: This is a grid/coordinate based drawing app, so simply drawing a line is not possible. It is necessary to get all the coordinates between the points. What I'm having trouble is creating the midpoints action, so it doesn't have to be done manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the mid points and call the recusion only if the mid point is different than one of the left or right point.

```js
function midpoint(a, b) {
    return Math.floor((a + b) / 2);
}

function drawPoints(p0, p1) {
    var middle = [midpoint(p0[0], p1[0]), midpoint(p0[1], p1[1])];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(middle[0], middle[1], 1, 1);
    ctx.closePath();
    if ((p0[0] !== middle[0] || p0[1] !== middle[1]) && (p1[0] !== middle[0] || p1[1] !== middle[1])) {
        drawPoints(p0, middle);
        drawPoints(middle, p1);
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

drawPoints([0,0], [600, 20]);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border-width: 0; display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0;" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var points = [];
            function findMid(x,y){ 
                var mid  = parseInt((x+y)/2);
                if(x!=mid && y!=mid){
                    points.push(mid);
                    console.log("x:"+x+" y:"+y+" mid:"+mid);
                    findMid(x,mid);
                    findMid(y,mid);
              }     
            }
            initialPointX = 4;
            initialPointY = 10;
            console.log(findMid(initialPointX,initialPointY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function on each recursion should

1. Create the midpoint between A and B, say C
2. Call itself on (A, C) and (B, C)
3. Stop if A == B or A is very close to B

In code this would be like this:

```
function placeMidPoint(Ax, Ay, Bx, By) {
  var e = 0; // some small number, if e==0 then you're stopping when A==B
  if( (Ax - Bx) < e && (Ay - By) < e )
    return;
  var Cx = findMidpoint(Ax, Bx);
  var Cy = findMidpoint(Ay, By);
  setPoint(Cx, Cy);

  placeMidPoint(Ax, Ay, Cx, Cy);
  placeMidPoint(Cx, Cy, Bx, By);
}
```